# Match only a file's base name (filename without extension) with a regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

In PowerShell, I want to compare a file's name. The file has the name as *someFileName.docx*. I am using the following cmdlet:

```
$tmpTarget["Name"] -match $name
```

sometimes the `$tmpTarget["Name"]` has a file extension and sometimes it doesn't.

so I want a regular expression that will only `-match` the file name, but ignore the extension.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the base name only (the file name without extension), it's **simpler to use [`[IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension) first** and match the result:

```bash
[IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($tmpTarget["Name"]) -eq $name
```

Note that after extracting the base file name with the .NET method,   `-eq` rather than `-match` can be used to perform a literal, whole-value  comparison against `$name` (`-match` matches *substrings* by default, and would also require escaping [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) metacharacters such as `[`, `(` and `+` in `$name` in order for those characters to be taken *literally*).

In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** (but not in *Windows PowerShell*), you can alternatively use 
**[`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) `-LeafBase`**:

```bash
# PowerShell *Core* only.
# -> 'someFileName'
Split-Path -LeafBase 'someFileName.docx'

# With comparison:
(Split-Path -LeafBase 'someFileName.docx') -eq $name
```

---

**If you do want to use a single regular expression**, you can use the following, but it's significantly more complex:

```bash
$tmpTarget["Name"] -match ('^{0}(?:\.|$)' -f [regex]::Escape($name))
```

- `^` anchors matching at the start of the string
- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing subexpression
- `{0}` is a placeholder for the[`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)'s first operand, i.e. the base name to match, *escaped* in order to be interpreted *literally* using [`[regex]::Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape).
- `\.|$` either matches a literal `.` (`\.`) - the start of an extension - or (`|`) the end of the string (`$`) - in case there is no extension.

The above works fine if your file names only ever have at most *1* extension, such as `someFileName` or `someFileName.docx`.

---

**If your file names may have *multiple* extensions**, such as `someFileName.foo.docx`, and you only want to ignore the *last* extension, a little more work is needed:

```bash
$name = 'someFileName.foo'
# -> $true - 'someFileName.foo' matches in full, because only .docx is ignored.
'someFileName.foo.docx' -match ('^{0}(?:\.[^.]*$|$)' -f [regex]::Escape($name))
```

- Subexpression `\.[^.]*$` only matches the *last* extension: a literal `.` (`\.`) followed by something *other* than `.` (`[^.]`) zero or more times (`*`) through the end of the string (`$`).

Answer (score 2):

As file names could have multiple dots contained it's difficult to decide if the last dot separated part is meant to be an extension.

But if the BaseName is known simply make the extension optional

```
$name = [RegEx] 'someFileName(\.docx)?'
$tmpTarget["Name"] -match $name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-replace` operator for this. It will output the file base name without the extension.

```
$tmpTarget["Name"] -replace "\.[^.]*$"
```

If you already know all of the possible extensions, you can do something like the following, which will only remove the known extension if it is present.

```
$tmpTarget["Name"] -replace "(\.docx|\.xlsx|\.txt)$"
```

**Explanation:**

`-replace` uses a regex match to select a string and replaces it with a string. `\.[^.]*$` matches the final `.` character and then greedily matches all characters except newlines and dots until the end of string (`$`).

---

Issues with the first solution will be if there are file names with `.` characters   ***when the extension is not present***. Knowing the extensions up front can make the matching more reliable.

The way to avoid all of the text manipulation is to use System.IO.FileInfo objects. Those objects have all of the file parts you are looking for separated into properties.

Comment: If the file extension is known, it's probably safer to just remove that, instead of blindly removing everything after a dot, which _may_ be a valid character in the data they want to match.

Comment: The best way is to work with FileInfo objects and not do any of this text manipulation.

Comment: Well, yes, but some people insist on using PowerShell in weird and horrible ways.